# Why am I getting an undefined offset:124 in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined, offset

I don't know what the issue is. Everything is defined with exception of maybe $scanDir? It's part of a function though so the value of that is passed when it's called. That shouldn't be the cause.

```
for ($a = 0; $a <= count($scanListArrayOrig); $a++) {
    rename($scanDir . '/' . $scanListArrayOrig[$a], $scanDir . '/' . $scanListArrayNew[$a]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<=` with `<`.

```
for ($a = 0; $a < count($scanListArrayOrig); $a++) {
    rename($scanDir . '/' . $scanListArrayOrig[$a], $scanDir . '/' . $scanListArrayNew[$a]);
}
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/yvvAxL

Comment: Wasn't thinking about offset since arrays start with [0]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a foreach and check the new array of existing the key:

```
foreach($scanListArrayOrig as $key => $file) {
    if(false === array_key_exists($key, $scanListArrayNew)) {
        //new filename not existing in array
    }
    else {
        rename($scanDir.'/'.$file, $scanDir.'/'.$scanListArrayNew[$key]);
    }
}
```